# How disable eslint-loader of storybook's webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint, storybook

I would like disable eslint-loader of storybook's webpack, cuz I use other process to validate the code's quality.

I know exists the webpack's config about storybook like code below and maybe I could use some filter on `config.rules`, but maybe isn't good:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = async ({ config }) => {
  // some modifications

  return config
}
```

I've trying searching on storybook's docs about this, but didn't find anything about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've had a similar problem, In my case I was using create-react-app and [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra) to disable eslint, since I'm also using my own linter config, but I run into a problem with Storybook using different linting rules, and complaining about my source code.

I then realised that I could just look at the source code of customize-cra to find out how they disabled eslint in webpack and it worked.

```
disableEsLint = (e) => {
  return e.module.rules.filter(e =>
    e.use && e.use.some(e => e.options && void 0 !== e.options.useEslintrc)).forEach(s => {
      e.module.rules = e.module.rules.filter(e => e !== s)
    }), e
}

module.exports = function ({ config }) {
  // Same config, except it is missing the eslint rule
  config = disableEsLint(config);

  // Do any thing else you want here
  config.module.rules.unshift({
    test: /\.story\.tsx?$/,
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve('@storybook/addon-storysource/loader'),
        options: { parser: 'typescript' },
      },
    ],
    enforce: 'pre',
  });

  // return the new config
  return config;
};
```

I'm not sure if this will work for your case but it worth a try.

Other suggestions are try to console log config in webpack, find the rule's name and `config.module.rules.delete('your-rule-name')`

In my case rules didn't have a name / or I coudn't find it.

Comment: it worked for me, I have added it to `.storybook/main.js`

look at this link: https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/#full-control-mode

Answer (score 16):

Solution with `plugin instanceof EslintWebpackPlugin` didn't help me, but this approach helped:

```
//.storybook/main.js

module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: config => {
    return {
      ...config,
      plugins: config.plugins.filter(plugin => {
        if (plugin.constructor.name === 'ESLintWebpackPlugin') {
          return false
        }
        return true
      }),
    }
  },
}
```

P.S. the new version will have a CLI parameter to disable eslint: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/13452, `6.2.0-alpha.7` already supports it

Comment: What will be the cli parameter? Can't find it in the PR or `npx start-storybook --help`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [this](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/#using-your-existing-config) example for understanding how to customize storybook's default config.

Then you need to filter the **rules** array in that config.

```
module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    return {
      ...config,
      module: {
      rules: config.module.rules.filter(rule => {
        if (!rule.use) return true;
        return !rule.use.find(
          useItem => typeof useItem.loader === 'string' && useItem.loader.includes('eslint-loader'),
        );
      }),
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems that newer storybook versions use the [eslint-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/eslint-webpack-plugin/) instead, so the needed change now looks something like this:

```
--- a/.storybook/main.js
+++ b/.storybook/main.js
@@ -1,3 +1,6 @@
+// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
+const EslintWebpackPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
+
 module.exports = {
    stories: ['./stories/*.stories.tsx'],
    addons: [
@@ -8,4 +11,17 @@ module.exports = {
        '@storybook/addon-links',
        '@storybook/addon-controls',
    ],
+   webpackFinal: config => {
+       return {
+           ...config,
+           plugins: config.plugins.filter(plugin => {
+               // Remove the eslint-webpack-plugin: We already check our code, storybook doesn't need to bother
+               // doing it again with potentially different options.
+               if (plugin instanceof EslintWebpackPlugin) {
+                   return false;
+               }
+               return true;
+           }),
+       };
+   },
 };
```

Answer (score 3):

storybook v6.3: from the default config, just comment out the create-react-app preset addon:

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    // '@storybook/preset-create-react-app'    - HERE - comment this out
  ],
  typescript: {
    check: false,
    checkOptions: {},
    reactDocgen: 'react-docgen-typescript',
    reactDocgenTypescriptOptions: {
      shouldExtractLiteralValuesFromEnum: true,
      propFilter: (prop) => (prop.parent ? !/node_modules/.test(prop.parent.fileName) : true),
    },
  },
};
```

create react app preset will stop your build if it finds eslint 'error', which in my opinion is super stupid

Comment: Removing this preset makes the build fail altogether (ModuleParseError). With the preset still in place, the build completes albeit no stories work after opening the browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true` option in npm scripts to start storybook.
The following npm scripts disable eslint-loader of storybook's webpack.

```
"storybook": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true start-storybook -p 6006 -s public ",
```

Comment: Do you have any documentation to back this up? I have tried this and it did not work. Googling this approach did not returns any results either.

Comment: Seem to work for me. I use it as follows: `"start:storybook": "env DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true start-storybook -p 6006 -s public"`

Note `env` before setting env variable